# Where should i put .ttf files in flask

Tags: python, css, flask

I am completely new to `flask` and I didn't find an answer related to this question. Where should I put my `.ttf` files and how to use them in `.css` files?.
I'm sorry if this question is duplicate.

Comment: Please, explain more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it depends on your logic how you structure your project.

static assets (`css`, `fonts`, `images` and `js` .. files) can be **loaded** from

- the default **project** `static` folder (this [topic](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/?highlight=flask#application-object)) for global assets like `bootstrap` or `jquery` libs
- the default **blueprint** `static` folder (this [topic](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#blueprint-objects)) with local scope for particular page

```
flaskapp / the root folder project

.. 

.. flaskapp

   .. errors (blueprint)
        templates
        __init__.py
        views.py

   .. home (blueprint)
      .. static
         .. css
         .. fonts
            .. .ttf             -- here (local asset)
         .. js

      .. templates
      .. __init__.py
      .. forms.py
      .. models.py
      .. views.py

   .. static
      .. css
         .. bootstrap
         .. fontawsome
      .. fonts
         .. .ttf               -- here (global asset)
      .. js
         .. jquery

   .. templtes

   .. __init__.py
   .. flaskapp.py

.. tests
.. venv
.. .flaskenv
```

Answer (score 0):

You would put the .ttf files in the `static` folder, `.css`, `.js`, etc. also belong there.

For example in your website you might want to put this in:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: some-font;
  src: url( {{ url_for('static', filename='yourFontHere.ttf') }} ;
}
```

There is no need to import any other Flask functions as Flask handles `url_for`.